# Update worldVelocity to the latest Unity version

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm migrating my `Unity Android` application to the newest version.

I have this code line:

```
GetComponent<ParticleEmitter>().worldVelocity = new Vector3 (Random.Range(-10,10),0,Random.Range(-10,10));
```

In the previous version it was working ok, but in the newest one, I get this error:

> ParticleEmitter is deprecated

And `worldVelocity` is not available anymore.

How can I update this specific line, BUT using `ParticleSystem` ?

Comment: Unity created a script to help update projects with deprecated particle systems. See [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/release-legacy-particle-system-updater.510879/).  I'm not sure if this will solve your issue since it mentions it cannot automatically update scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't translate the line perfectly because of how particle systems have changed but you can get close.  The old `worldVelocity` property defined the starting velocity of each particle (in world space).  Now, `ParticleSystem` has a [`main` property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-main.html) that returns a [`MainModule` object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MainModule.html).  This module has a [`startSpeed` property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MainModule-startSpeed.html) which you would use to configure the information you need.

Your line would look something like this:

```
GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().main.startSpeed =
    new ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve(0.0f, 10.0f);
```

Note that the old code you posted is a velocity and not a speed and that's due to the numerous changes in how particles are handled by Unity. Beyond that line of code, you're going to need to read up on the [Particle System Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysUsage.html) to really get a handle on how they now work with min-max curves.